# how to animate UIImageview exactly pages of books

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, xcode5.0.1

I have gone through various posts for animating `UIImageview` like
    books pages but didn't find anything useful.
    Actually I want to have animation on `UIImageView` to have the same effect as we have while
    turning books's pages. I have used the following code to turn the `UIImageview`:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.greetingImgView
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
```

But I am not able to get the desired page curl animation as we have while turning books pages.
    I want a kind of animation where the user can have a feel of book page animation while viewing animation.
    Please help me; I have researched a lot.

Comment: The above animation block does nothing or is it just that it didn't turn out as you wanted?

Comment: @Unheilig i am able to have a animation but i want such kind of animation like turning books pages in real.

Comment: Please check this link
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763498/flip-greeting-card-like-just-wink-app/20764087#20764087

Comment: @ankit yadav can you please provide me with some tutorial..

Answer (score 0):

if you want a book like interface for your app, why not using the `UIPageViewController`. This class provides all you need and you can set the pageing animation as you want.

Comment: can you please provide me with some tutorial link?