# flip greeting card like just wink app

Tags: objective-c, animation, ios6, ios7, xcode5

Can anyone help me in making animation like we have in Just Wink App.I want to have the same preview animation as in Just Wink.
[here is the animation which i want to have](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srnRuhFvYl0&feature=youtu.be)

I have tried a lot for hours but didn't find anything useful.I tried the similar animation using CATransform3D but not able to get the exact one with this also .Here is the code that i have tried

```
intialTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
intialTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
intialTransform = CATransform3DRotate(intialTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(70), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
_myView1.layer.transform = intialTransform;
```

i take three view as above like _myView2 and_myview3 and have CATransform3DIdentity for everyone.I am able to rotate the different view like in Just Wink but not able to gain the exact animation.
Tried a lot for samples but that also didm;t solve my problem.
Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code sample for review "open card" animation in implementation which work for me.
Just insert the code in the new "single view" project and run.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *insideView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *pageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *backPageView;
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect cardFrame;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if ([touch locationInView:[self view]].x <= CGRectGetMaxX(_cardFrame)) {

    float dx = ([touch locationInView:[self view]].x - CGRectGetMaxX(_cardFrame)) / _cardFrame.size.width;

    //create perspective
    CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
    mt.m34 = 1.0/-500.;

    //create rotation
    CATransform3D open = CATransform3DMakeRotation( -dx * M_PI_2, 0, - 1, 0);

    //create result transform
    CATransform3D openTransform = CATransform3DConcat(open, mt);

    //apply transforms
    [[_pageView layer] setTransform:openTransform];
    [[_backPageView layer] setTransform:openTransform];
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

  //create frame for 2 test views
  CGFloat size = 200.0;
  _cardFrame = CGRectMake([[self view] center].x - size / 2, [[self view] center].y - size / 2 , size, size);

  //lower view
  _insideView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: _cardFrame];
  [_insideView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

  //upper view
  _pageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_cardFrame];
  [_pageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

  //upper view back side
  _backPageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_cardFrame];
  [_backPageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

  [[self view] addSubview:_insideView];
  [[self view] addSubview:_pageView];
  [[self view] insertSubview:_backPageView belowSubview:_pageView];

  //get layer of upper view and set needed property
  CALayer *viewLayer = [_pageView layer];
  CALayer *viewBackLayer = [_backPageView layer];

  [viewLayer setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint){0.0 , 0.5}];
  [viewLayer setFrame:_cardFrame];
  [viewLayer setDoubleSided:NO];
  [viewBackLayer setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint){0.0 , 0.5}];
  [viewBackLayer setFrame:_cardFrame];

  //create perspective
  CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
  mt.m34 = 1.0/-500.;

  //create rotation
  CATransform3D open = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI_4, 0, - 1, 0);

  //create result transform
  CATransform3D openTransform = CATransform3DConcat(open, mt);

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
   {
     //close animation
     [viewLayer setTransform:openTransform];
     [viewBackLayer setTransform:openTransform];
   } completion:^(BOOL finished)
   {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
      {
        //close animation
        [viewLayer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
        [viewBackLayer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
      }];
   }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks!!!how can we have images on these view so that one can view the other view back portion as shown in this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587125/how-to-do-flipping-greeting-card-in-ios

Comment: @ankyy You need to make the correct hierarchy of layers (UIView can contain more then 1 layer). For example: `layer` will contain a mirrored image inside of the page, and a `sublayer`(added to `layer`) - outside normal image. As alternative: use two UIView (first above second using `insertSubview:aboveSubview:` or  `insertSubview: belowSubview:`) animated synchronously and contain different images.

Comment: can u please tell me how to keep on opening and closing the UIVIEW using touch gesture as the person will swipe on UIView to open it slowly slowly according to fingers swiped.

Comment: as i am new to this technology ..should i add the gesture on UIView?

Comment: @ankyy You can add the gesture or use `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:` and `touchesEnded:` methods for processing touches or use both together. In `touchesMoved:` you can get current location and previous location of touch and use it for page transformation angle calculation.

Comment: thanks for your quick response..Can u please tell me the process of page transformation angle calculation.I can get the current and previous location but don't know what to do after that .Don't know how to rotate that touched view and move it accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, in these calculations , much depends on the location of objects. The only thing to which you can bind - coordinates edge species, which rotates relative to page . When the X -axis coordinate of touch and the edges are the same - this corresponds to a rotation of 90 degrees . If the coordinates of the touch on the X -axis coordinate more edge - angle less than 90 degrees , if the coordinates of the touch on the X -axis coordinate is less than the edge - an angle greater than 90 degrees. Need knowledge of trigonometry to align the angle of rotation and movement touch.

Comment: @ankyy I'm change code in answer. Now you can see how you can do user interaction with "card" and how make different "page" sides. It's not a perfect example - but its purpose only to show a possible way of solving the problem.

Comment: now i am able to do show preview effect as i want…i want one more help from your side..i have seen just wink preview effect after opening the card,how to have the same effect of seeing the 2nd page and 3rd page of the card by just clicking the page it shift the touched page to the viewing area.Thanks once again

Comment: @ankyy If I understand the question you need use `touchesBegan:` or `touchesEnded:` (second more preferred) for it. For check touch location use `CGRectContainsPoint (rect_of_page, point_of_touch )`.

Comment: can you please tell me what to do when we have four pages in greeting card and i want to have the same turn effect with gesture on all pages as you u have done above.

Comment: Hard to say. Effect of four pages can be implemented in several ways. You can assign each page of your views (even two - for the right and left halves of the page). Or can be used to display two views of an open card and two for animated pages and change their contents and visibility programmatically before and after the animation.

Comment: using this the page opened from left and goes towards right.How to make the page to animate  from bottom and make it to go upwards while opening.

Comment: @ankyy you need change `CATransform3D open = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI_4, 0, - 1, 0);` to `CATransform3D open = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3 * M_PI_4, 1, 0, 0);` and change anchor point from `{0.0 , 0.5}` to `{0.5 , 0.0}`

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko, Hey, I used your code, It useful for me but I added fourth view and I have to animate to close the card, I am stuck on that can you please help on it. Thanks :)